# writing and running a code

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Just a funny question for whom are clever in ROS!
I have read the tutorial just for well understanding checking I ask the following question? (Please do not refer me to Tutorial)
What are the main steps of a written and execution of C++ code in ROS
1-writing a C++ code
2-making cmake
3-run roscpp
Is there any other files that there is obligation to make before running?
(What about launch file or others? Is there any obligation?)
Thanks
Fi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216227/writing-and-running-a-code/) by [Fi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22677/fi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can start every ros packet without a launch  or yaml file (rosrun ). with roslunch you have an fremework for automaik starting and dependency chake for sub launsch files. you can starte every node by hand with an call of rosrun for everey node or you start the whole system witch one call of roslaunch

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22677/fi/) on 2015-08-21**:
I appreciate it if you reply me